# loop through array that has different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to loop through an array that has may or may not contain a value. The second car has a car feature and the first does not. I'm trying to put each iteration in an object that contains the values if they exist. I'm getting two objects but both are identical.

Ex.

```
    let arr = [{
    'carType': 'sedan',
    'carInfo': 
    {
      'carMake': 'ford',
      'carModel':'torus'
    }
   },
   {
   'carType': 'suv',
   'carInfo': 
   {
     'carMake': 'nissan',
     'carModel':'rogue',
     'carFeature': 'X'
   }
   }
 }]
```

forEach ex.

```
            let cars = [];
            let carInfos = {}
            carInfo.forEach((car) => {
                carInfos.carType = car.carType;
                if(car.carInfo !== null) {
                    carInfos.carMake = car.carMake;
                    if(car.carInfo.carFeature !== null) {
                        if(car.carInfo.carFeature === 'X') {
                            carInfos.carFeature = car.carInfo.carFeature
                        }
                    }
                }
                cars.push(carInfos)
            });
```

Comment: `let carInfos = {}` should be inside the loop

Comment: wait this worked! that was it?? sorry can you explain a little why it worked @WebbH

Comment: You need `carInfos` to be an empty object at the beginning of each loop. When it's outside the loop, it still has all the changes from the previous iteration

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Car` model and utilize the constructor to assign all of the values to the properties.

Comment: right but some values exist in some objects and not in others so i don't want to populate where they don't exist

Comment: Exactly. By using the constructor the values will only be assigned if they exist and will remain undefined otherwise. Does this not work for you?

Comment: no, i don't want to send an undefined property. WebbH solved this question in the comments for me. thanks!